# Server is automatically taking an input from the client instead of waiting in Java

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

UPDATE:
I tried hardcoding the password and letting the user be input, it just skipped the input part like this:

```
Please press one to sign in or two to sign up if you haven't already1
Please enter your credentials below
Username:
Password:
Your username and/or password are incorrect, access has been denied
```

UPDATE 2:
I tried the following 2 fixes and non worked:

Fix 1 client

```
                System.out.println(inputFromServer.readUTF());
                int choice = scan.nextInt();
                outputToServer.writeInt(choice);
                System.out.println(inputFromServer.readUTF());
                String username = scan.nextLine();
                outputToServer.writeUTF(username);
                System.out.println(inputFromServer.readUTF());
                scan.next(); 
                String password = scan.nextLine();
                outputToServer.writeUTF(password);
                System.out.println(inputFromServer.readUTF());
```

fix 1 server:

```
outputToClient.writeUTF("Please enter your username");
                        Username = inputFromClient.readUTF();
                        outputToClient.writeUTF("Password:");
                        inputFromClient.readUTF();
                        Password = inputFromClient.readUTF();
```

fix 2 client:

```
                System.out.println(inputFromServer.readUTF());
                int choice = scan.nextInt();
                scan.next();
                outputToServer.writeInt(choice);
                System.out.println(inputFromServer.readUTF());
                String username = scan.nextLine();
                outputToServer.writeUTF(username);
                System.out.println(inputFromServer.readUTF());
                String password = scan.nextLine();
                outputToServer.writeUTF(password);
                System.out.println(inputFromServer.readUTF());
```

fix 2 server:

```
    outputToClient.writeUTF("Please enter your username");
                        Username = inputFromClient.readUTF();
                        outputToClient.writeUTF("Password:");
                        inputFromClient.readUTF();
                        Password = inputFromClient.readUTF();
```

I am writing a client-server code in Java where the client has to choose between signing in or signing up and then he needs to input his info accordingly, however, I am facing some bugs.

From the client-side, I have the following:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultipleClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");

            Socket socket = new Socket(ip, 8189);

            // Receiving input and sending output to Server
            DataInputStream inputFromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream outputToServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            while (true) {

                System.out.println(inputFromServer.readUTF());
                int choice = scan.nextInt();
                outputToServer.writeInt(choice);
                System.out.println(inputFromServer.readUTF());
                String username = scan.nextLine();
                outputToServer.writeUTF(username);
                System.out.println(inputFromServer.readUTF());
                String password = scan.nextLine();
                outputToServer.writeUTF(password);
                System.out.println(inputFromServer.readUTF());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

While from the server-side, I have the following:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MultipleServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8189);

        // Server keeps on receiving new Clients
        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            try {
                // ServerSocket waits for a Client to connect
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                System.out.println("A new client is connected : " + clientSocket);

                // Receiving input and sending output to Client
                DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                System.out.println("Assigning new thread for this client");

                System.out
                        .println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

                // Create a new Thread object for the Client
                Thread thread = new ClientHandler(clientSocket, inputFromClient, outputToClient);
                thread.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                clientSocket.close();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

// ClientHandler class
class ClientHandler extends Thread {
    final Socket clientSocket;
    final DataInputStream inputFromClient;
    final DataOutputStream outputToClient;

    // Constructor
    public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket, DataInputStream inputFromClient, DataOutputStream outputToClient) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.inputFromClient = inputFromClient;
        this.outputToClient = outputToClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Variables
        String Username = "";
        String Password = "";
        int choice;
        String toreturn;
        while (true) {
            try {
                // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
                // broken Java implementations

                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // handle the error
            }

            Connection conn = null;

            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" + "?user=root&password=test");

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                // handle any errors
                System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
                System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
                System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
            }

            try {

                outputToClient.writeUTF("Please press one to sign in or two to sign up if you haven't already");
                choice = inputFromClient.readInt();

                if (choice != 1 && choice != 0) {
                    outputToClient.writeUTF("Please choose one of the listed choices");
                } else {
                    if (choice == 1) {
//here is where the problem is occuring
                        outputToClient.writeUTF("Please enter your credentials below\n");
                        outputToClient.writeUTF("Username:");
                        Username = inputFromClient.readUTF();
                        outputToClient.writeUTF("Password:");
                        Password = inputFromClient.readUTF();
                        String queryoneresult = "";

//execution isn't reaching this part so I don't think it is relevant but I included it anyway
                        ResultSet rs = null;

                        PreparedStatement stmt = conn
                                .prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(Username)\n" + "  FROM Authentication\n"
                                        + " WHERE Username = ? AND\n" + "       Password = ? \n" + " LIMIT 0, 1");
                        stmt.setString(1, Username);
                        stmt.setString(2, Password);

                        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                        if (stmt.execute()) {
                            rs = stmt.getResultSet();
                        }
                        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                        int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
                                if (i > 1)
                                    System.out.print(" ");
                                String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
                                queryoneresult = rs.getString(i);
                            }
                        }

                        if (Integer.valueOf(queryoneresult) == 1) {
                            outputToClient.writeUTF("Username and password have been verified, you can now proceed ");
                        } else {
                            outputToClient
                                    .writeUTF("Your username and/or password are incorrect, access has been denied");
                        }

                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

My problem is that I am getting the following output:

```
Please press one to sign in or two to sign up if you haven't already
1
Please enter your credentials below

Username:
sergio
Password:
Your username and/or password are incorrect, access has been denied
```

so it seems like the server is automatically getting a response for the password and proceeding like this, had executions that looked like this too:

```
Please press one to sign in or two to sign up if you haven't already
1
Please enter your credentials below

Username:
Password:
sergio
Your username and/or password are incorrect, access has been denied
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) your writeUTF and readUTF calls don't match up in the client and server. In particular, when you `outputToClient.writeUTF("Please enter your credentials below\n");` in the server, this is written out in the client just before you enter the username. Thus your username is read in after the "Credentials" prompt, and the password is read in after the "Username" prompt.

Comment: 2) Your `scan.nextInt()` followed by `scan.nextLine()` causes an empty string to be read in by `scan.nextLine()`. This is because the newline you enter to terminate the integer is not discarded, and causes the subsequent nextLine() to return immediately with an empty string. The simplest solution is to call `scan.next()` immediately after `scan.nextInt()`.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk would you mind showing how the edited code will be? I didn't really get how to do it instead

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I updated the post and fix 2 includes what I understood from your 2 comments